# Android emulator - simulate particular device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to simulate LG K4 2017:

https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_k4_(2017)-8489.php

Size    5.0 inches, 69.6 cm2 (~66.3% screen-to-body ratio)

Resolution  480 x 854 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~195 ppi density)

I'm trying to do that in AVD manager, I set the same screen size and resolution, however app looks very different (on the real device everything is much bigger, in other words I can see less content).

Here's how the settings look like:

[image]

I think screen size should be normal, but there's no way to change that - it's automatically changing according to screen size and resolution.

Is it possible to somehow change to simulate this device?

Comment: Maybe density is different from emulator to device you are trying to run ?

Comment: you can't actually generate pixel perfect AVD to make it similar to real device, there is always some difference, due to screen size, dpi, ppi etc (for some devices it may work, I have also faced the same issues, specifically for Tablets)

Comment: If it's just a little off I'm fine. But I have a screenshot from my app taken on LG K4 and no matter what settings I'd set it doesn't come close to this look.

Comment: @Makalele have you tried Genymotion? perhaps it may work on Genymotion AVD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the text on the screenshot is larger because the [display size settings](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006972?hl=en) on the LG K4 were set to something larger than default. I've run into this error a few times, where an application would look completely different when viewed on different phones of the same size because of this setting.

As far as I know, it is not possible to simulate exact display sizes with the Android Emulator. Also, if it were possible, it would not guarantee looking the same as the actual phone as most manufacturers have custom settings and skins which cannot be replicated by the emulator.

Comment: Looks like that's a correct answer to this problem. Guess I cannot do anything, but to tell device owner to try setting these display settings back to defaults.

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio** tries to render high quality **Android Virtual Devices (AVDs)** out of the box.

If you have tried **Android Studio** and it still hasn't worked out I recommend using a third party e.g. **Genymotion**.

They offer a free tier; i.e. a license to use their **Virtual Devices/AVDs** (**customized** or from **manufacturers**) for **free personal use**.

Following are steps for setting up **Genymotion**.

Visit the **Genymotion** website [specifically this link](https://www.genymotion.com/account/create/) to create an account.

[image: CreateAnAccount]

The next step after filling the form above is activating your account.

[image: AccountActivationMessage]

Clicking the link sent to you via email should send you to the screen below.

[image: AccountActivationSuccessful]

Click the **download genymotion for personal use** button. This sends you to the page below look for the **Download Genymotion Personal Edition** button just above the robots head.

[image: Download a free to use edition of Genymotion]

Next you'll see a log in page.

[image: Log into Genymotion]

Next is the download page choose a version based on your platform.

[image: Choose Genymotion version]

Choose the download that comes packaged with **VirtualBox** as **Genymotion** requires **VirtualBox** to run in your local environment.

Once the download is complete install **Genymotion** on your machine.

I'm installing it on a mac (double click the **dmg** installation file).

[image: GenyMotionInstallationFile]

Move Genymotion to the Applications folder.

[image: MoveGenyMotionToApplicationsFolder]

Launch the **Genymotion** desktop application.

[image: GenymotionDesktopApplicationOnmacOS]

[image: GenymotionFlashscreen]

You should be prompted to sign in again.

[image: SignIntoGenymotion]

In the next screen you are prompted to choose a license; go with **Personal Use**.

[image: Choosing a Genymotion license]

Then agree to the terms and conditions.

[image: GenymotionEULA]

Once logged in you'll see a list of devices from which you can select
or you can build your own custom device.

[image: DeviceList]

Scroll to the bottom to find the **add custom device** button.

[image: AddCustomDeviceButton]

On clicking the above button you are presented with a dialog to configure your custom device.

[image: CustomizeGenymotionDevice]

Once done click the **confirm** button and watch the progress in **Genymotion**.

[image: DeviceGettingCreated]

When **Genymotion** is done creating your device click on the device's three button menu to the far right. Here there is an option to start the device.

[image: StartDeviceMenuOption]

**Genymotion** should start booting your device.

[image: BootingVirtualDevice]

[image: DeviceBooting]

And voila your device is up and running.

[image: UpAndRunning]

Here is the launcher app in your new device.

[image: AppLauncher]

Over in **Android Studio** your device should be listed in the **connected devices dropdown menu** in the **Logcat**.

[image]

I have no affiliation to **Genymotion** and won't receive anything from this recommendation. I just use their desktop application when doing testing for my **Android** projects.

Further information regarding **Genymotion** can be found [here](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/).

Hopefully this should get you closer to your goal.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer - I'll definitely try it out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see as soon as you select 5 inch it selects density as mdpi.
Modify the attribute hw.lcd.density=195 at avd config file: /Users/yourUserName/.android/avd/YourDevice.avd/config.ini, and reboot your virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a comment saying to edit **config.ini** and that fix for me.

- open AVG manager
- right mouse click and select **Show on Disk**
- open the file **config.ini**
- change **hw.lcd.density** value to **240** (hw.lcd.density=240)
- start the device emulator

that did that trick for me.

Comment: Before I got a error: 
Bad LCD density: 195. Available densities are: 120, 160, 213, 240, 280, 320, 360, 400, 420, 440, 480, 560, 640.

So I just keep trying one of the available values until I got the result that I want. 240 looks the right one for me

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me when I tried to Simulate Samsung A8, but it was a display setting issue (Font size were larger on the Real device and smaller on emulator).
You may check pixel density as well.